# Why is my Plotly bar chart stacking bars in the same category?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a bar chart showing number of meeting rooms in use for a building across time. Initially this graph worked as intended, but then I added data for more floors, and the bars have become stacked even though data should be in the same category:

[image]For example, the bar for 10am, Monday, Week 1 shows 4, 6, and 1 meeting rooms in use all stacked on top of each other instead of 1 bar reading 11. "Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor" just contains an integer value calculated by counting 0s in a column that indicates a room is empty.

Here is my code:

```
NUMBER OF MEETING ROOMS IN USE

import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a new column with zeros
dframe_meeting['Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor'] = 0

# Update the column with the calculated sum
dframe_meeting.loc[dframe_meeting['Type'] == 'Meeting Room', 'Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor'] = dframe_meeting[
    (dframe_meeting['Type'] == 'Meeting Room')].groupby(['Building','Week', 'Day', 'Time','Floor'])['Hours in Use'].transform('sum')

# Create a new data frame and import relevant columns
df_meeting_all_floors = dframe_meeting[['Week', 'Day', 'Time', 'Floor', 'Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor', 'Number of Meeting Rooms x Floor']].dropna()
df_meeting_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors.drop_duplicates()


# Create a column for time slot

df_meeting_all_floors['Week'] = df_meeting_all_floors['Week'].astype(str)
df_meeting_all_floors['Time Slot'] = df_meeting_all_floors['Time'] + ', ' + df_meeting_all_floors['Day'] + ', Week ' + df_meeting_all_floors['Week']

df_meeting_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors.sort_values(by=['Time Slot'])

# Sorting based on 'Time Slot' while keeping other columns in the same order
sort_order = df_meeting_all_floors['Time Slot'].argsort()
df_meeting_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors.iloc[sort_order]

# Using Plotly Graph Objects to create a bar chart including customized labels, colors, and widths
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=df_meeting_all_floors["Time Slot"],
                                                      y=df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"],
                                                      marker_color='#26A2ED')],)

fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_layout(title_text="Number of Meeting Rooms in Use for All Floors",
                                            template="simple_white",
                                            bargap=0.03,
                                            showlegend=False,
                                            height=700,
                                            width=1000,
                                            yaxis_range=[0, df_meeting_all_floors['Number of Meeting Rooms x Floor'].max()])

fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_yaxes(title_text="Number of Meeting Rooms in Use")
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_xaxes(title_text="Time")
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray=[
    "8am, Monday, Week 1", "9am, Monday, Week 1", "10am, Monday, Week 1", "11am, Monday, Week 1",
    "12pm, Monday, Week 1", "1pm, Monday, Week 1", "2pm, Monday, Week 1", "3pm, Monday, Week 1",
    "4pm, Monday, Week 1", "5pm, Monday, Week 1", "6pm, Monday, Week 1", "7pm, Monday, Week 1",
    "8pm, Monday, Week 1", "8am, Tuesday, Week 1", "9am, Tuesday, Week 1", "10am, Tuesday, Week 1",
    "11am, Tuesday, Week 1", "12pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "1pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "2pm, Tuesday, Week 1",
    "3pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "4pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "5pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "6pm, Tuesday, Week 1",
    "7pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "8pm, Tuesday, Week 1", "8am, Wednesday, Week 1", "9am, Wednesday, Week 1",
    "10am, Wednesday, Week 1", "11am, Wednesday, Week 1", "12pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "1pm, Wednesday, Week 1",
    "2pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "3pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "4pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "5pm, Wednesday, Week 1",
    "6pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "7pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "8pm, Wednesday, Week 1", "8am, Thursday, Week 1",
    "9am, Thursday, Week 1", "10am, Thursday, Week 1", "11am, Thursday, Week 1", "12pm, Thursday, Week 1",
    "1pm, Thursday, Week 1", "2pm, Thursday, Week 1", "3pm, Thursday, Week 1", "4pm, Thursday, Week 1",
    "5pm, Thursday, Week 1", "6pm, Thursday, Week 1", "7pm, Thursday, Week 1", "8pm, Thursday, Week 1"])


fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.add_hline(y=df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"].median())

# Adding the line for average population
med_meeting_rooms_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"].median()
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.layout.xaxis2 = go.layout.XAxis(overlaying='x', range=[0, 2], showticklabels=False)
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.add_scatter(x=[0, 2], y=[med_meeting_rooms_all_floors, med_meeting_rooms_all_floors], mode='lines+text', xaxis='x2', marker_color='Black',
                                          text='Median: ' + str(med_meeting_rooms_all_floors),
                                          textposition='top left',
                                          textfont=dict(color='Black'),
                                          name='citations',
                                          showlegend=False)

fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.show()
```

I have read the Plotly documentation: https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/. It addresses this issue and suggests using a histrogram instead. When I tried that I got a different chart that displays incorrect values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I recreated your data correctly, the stacking in your bar graph was due to there being different floors and buildings within the same time slot. After some small restructuring of your code it creates a bar graph like this:
[image]

The first step was summing the values in the column `Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor` which results in it becoming one column. This is what I think you were looking for.
The next step was making the columns `Week`, `Day`, and `Time` all ordered categorical values. After sorting it one these columns the bars appear in the correct order.

```
#NUMBER OF MEETING ROOMS IN USE

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a new column with zeros
dframe_meeting["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"] = 0

# Update the column with the calculated sum
dframe_meeting.loc[dframe_meeting["Type"] == "Meeting Room", "Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"] = dframe_meeting[
    (dframe_meeting["Type"] == "Meeting Room")].groupby(["Building","Week", "Day", "Time","Floor"])["Hours in Use"].transform("sum")

# Create a new data frame and import relevant columns
df_meeting_all_floors = dframe_meeting[["Week", "Day", "Time", "Floor", "Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor", "Number of Meeting Rooms x Floor"]].dropna()
df_meeting_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors.drop_duplicates()


# Create a column for time slot

df_meeting_all_floors["Week"] = df_meeting_all_floors["Week"].astype(str)
df_meeting_all_floors["Time Slot"] = df_meeting_all_floors["Time"] + ", " + df_meeting_all_floors["Day"] + ", Week " + df_meeting_all_floors["Week"]
# sum all rooms in use per time slot and recreate table
df_meeting_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors.groupby(["Time Slot", "Week","Day","Time"])["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"].sum().reset_index()

df_meeting_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors.astype({"Week": CategoricalDtype(categories=["1", "2", "3"], ordered=True),
                                                      "Day": CategoricalDtype(categories=["Monday","Teusday", "Wednesday","Thursday"], ordered=True),
                                                      "Time": CategoricalDtype(categories=["8am","9am","10am","11am","12pm","1pm","2pm","3pm","4pm","5pm","6pm","7pm"], ordered=True)})
df_meeting_all_floors.sort_values(by=["Week","Day","Time"], inplace=True)


# Using Plotly Graph Objects to create a bar chart including customized labels, colors, and widths
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=df_meeting_all_floors["Time Slot"],
                                                      y=df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"],
                                                      marker_color="#26A2ED")],)

fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_layout(title_text="Number of Meeting Rooms in Use for All Floors",
                                            template="simple_white",
                                            bargap=0.03,
                                            showlegend=False,
                                            height=700,
                                            width=1000,
                                            yaxis_range=[0, df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"].max()])

fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_yaxes(title_text="Number of Meeting Rooms in Use")
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.update_xaxes(title_text="Time")



fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.add_hline(y=df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"].median())

# Adding the line for average population
med_meeting_rooms_all_floors = df_meeting_all_floors["Meeting Rooms in Use x Floor"].median()
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.layout.xaxis2 = go.layout.XAxis(overlaying="x", range=[0, 2], showticklabels=False)
fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.add_scatter(x=[0, 2], y=[med_meeting_rooms_all_floors, med_meeting_rooms_all_floors], mode="lines+text", xaxis="x2", marker_color="Black",
                                          text="Median: " + str(med_meeting_rooms_all_floors),
                                          textposition="top left",
                                          textfont=dict(color="Black"),
                                          name="citations",
                                          showlegend=False)


fig_meeting_rooms_all_floors.show()
```